# Method for distributing points amongst answer/question editors?

Tags: discussion

I frequently see questions for which the second-most-upvoted answer is of the type "let me expand upon the first most upvoted answer." This answer really belongs as part of the first answer, but the second-answerer has minimal motivation (viz points) to edit the expansion directly into the first answer.  Indeed, performing more than basic structural edits seems to be a rare occurrence here on Stack Exchange.

OTOH, on wiki-style sites (which Stack Exchange is not, I understand) editing and creation are a more collaborative exercise. However, it still seems that rewarding deeper, more content-based edits would encourage editors to improve answers and questions in more meaningful ways.

What are some possible ways to reward more content-based edits on the Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kinda oddly - once reputation stops being a concern, there's a bit more incentive to do this.

In addition - I've always gone by 'respect the intent of the original poster' so *major* edits are kinda tricky. Some folks have done it, and let me know over comments - and my answer was so much better for it. *Othertimes* folks have commented additional information and I added it in myself. You'd not noticed these - with the latter I tend to credit the commenter, but it's hard to thank someone for a great edit that added a lot to your answer. Done right, you wouldn't notice these other than, well, hopefully how awesome the answer is.

And certainly the second answer has to have value on its *own* - otherwise it's no more than a glorified comment.

It also complicates what's a simple system - when do we decide who gets the reputation? Is it a split of overall reputation or do we add reputation? What happens with further edits?

The existing community wiki system handles it by divorcing reputation from it totally and had automatic triggers to convert a post to that state at one point. It... kind of hasn't worked that well and often gets used for off label applications. What you're suggesting is basically working out a way to add reputation to that.

Taking that framework - we could *roughly* work out how much of a post someone has posted - and maybe spread out reputation that way - until you start hitting fractions. Then you need to calculate who gets what - and sometimes edits might be too minor. You'd also have folks with major copy-editing fixes (which doesn't add to what the content is, but rather the digestibility of it). Some edits are bogus and some folk might try farming edits, so you'd need to have a framework to deal with that.

Or you can go "hey, so my answer's similar, but there's this neat thing. If you want I can add that to my post" if it's minor or post a new answer if its major.

Now, I've *sometimes* wished I could slice off a small amount of reputation as a bounty for an awesome edit, but it's rare enough that I've never really thought of meta-ing it.